# In a git merge, how do you just replace your version with the version git says there is a conflict with?

Tags: git, merge

I have two files: A and B. If I have been working on A and a partner is working on B, I want to merge files A and B. B is already committed. Let's say my partner already made the changes I was working on, so I just want to replace my A file with their B file - no merge needed. How do I resolve the conflict with git?

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Let's say both you and your partner modified the same file, and is committed to each respective repository.

```
git pull                             # fetch/merge partners changes
# merge fails, conflict
git checkout origin FILE_TO_REPLACE  # replace changes with partners ver
git commit                           # finish merge
```

Answer (score 36):

If their is a conflict during a merging operation (merge, cherry-pick, rebase, etc...) you can  resolve conflict by picking one side of the changes by doing :

`git checkout --ours <path>` (this will choose the local changes)

or

`git checkout --theirs <path>` (this will choose the remote changes)

then finishing resolving the conflict as usual with:

```
git add <path>
```

then commit with:

```
git commit
```