# How to update Master branch without fixing conflicts?

Tags: git

I have two branches `dev` and `master`.

I was working with `dev` branch and I didn't merge `dev` to `master`.

So `master` code is deprecated.

I want to update master, I want to merge my new code to `master` branch. But I don't want to fix conflicts, I just want to replace all old code of 'master' branch to new code of `dev` branch.

P.S. I would like to remove `master` branch and create new `master` branch with code of 'dev' branch but it is impossible in my case. Because I get this error:

> [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In a git merge, how do you just replace your version with the version git says there is a conflict with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515657/in-a-git-merge-how-do-you-just-replace-your-version-with-the-version-git-says-t)

Comment: Why impossible delete master? Just checkout dev, delete master branch, rename dev to master, pull to remote...

Comment: ! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)

Comment: check this post: http://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/gh_delete_master.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squashing all the difference into one new commit in master:

```
git checkout master
# point master to the same commit and files as dev:
git reset --hard dev
#the diff between dev & origin/master will now be in uncommitted files:
git reset --soft origin/master
#commit the diff:
git commit -m "Commit message that combines whatever was merged"
```

You could alternatively force-push (overwriting master completely) if you have permissions:

```
git push -f origin dev:refs/heads/master
```

Or you could remove master branch first and then create it again (if you have permissions):

```
git push origin :master
git push origin dev:refs/heads/master
```

Last 2 options are **unsafe** as they will result in confusion in case **someone already pulled master**.